# Transforming an integral over $R^n$ to a radius and a directional vector (aka Spherical-Radial)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

In several papers by John Monahan and Alan Genz there's mention of a spherical-radial transformation:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(\mathbf{x}) ~\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}
=
\int_0^\infty \int_{\mathbf{z}'\mathbf{z} = 1} f(r\mathbf{z}) ~r^{n-1} ~\mathrm{d}\mathbf{z}~\mathrm{d}r
$$
where $r$ is a radius and $\mathbf{z}$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  How does one show this?

I've been trying integration by substitution but I'm not sure how to handle the fact that the right side has $n+1$ variables plus a constraint and the left side has $n$ variables and no constraints.

Comment: Notice that using the standard norm on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ the vector $\mathbf{z}$ lies in the unit circle. So this is choosing co-ordinates $x \mapsto (r,\mathbf{z})$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ where $r= ||x||$ and $\mathbf{z} = x/||x||$. this is defined at all points except $0$  (but one point doesn't change the value of the integral). In three dimensions this is well-known spherical co-ordinates.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I get that the spaces defined in terms of $\mathbf{x}$ and $(r,\mathbf{z})$ are equivalent, but when I try to construct a Jacobian for the substitution things fall apart.  The Jacobian is not square since $(r,\mathbf{z})$ has $n+1$ entries.  I'm clearly missing something... any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Dear @neverKnowsBest let us look at some examples. In $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, the Jacobian is $dx= rdr d\theta$ where $\theta$ is the same as vector on the unit circle. In $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, $dX= r^{2}\sin(\theta)drd\theta d \phi$. Here $z=(\theta, \phi)$ is a point on the unit sphere and the differential form is $dz= \sin(\theta) d\theta d\phi$ (which is the same one you get from taking the equation of the sphere $x^{2}+ y^{2}+ z^{2} = 1$ and then writing $dxdy$ in terms of polar co-ordinates. The higher dimensional calculations are similar.(cont)

Comment: Note that the co-ordinate system $(r,z)$ has $n$ variables because of the constraint on $z$ that its norm is one. The points on a sphere $x_{1}^{2} + \ldots + x_{n}^{2} = 1$ inside $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ are $n-$dimensional and not $n+1$ dimensional.

Comment: Thanks for your patience DBS.  Is $\int f \sin(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta \mathrm{d}\phi$ the same as $\int_{z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2 =1} f \mathrm{d}\mathbf{z}$ for $\mathbf{z} = (z_1,z_2,z_3)$?